# White bar appearing when hovering over modal button

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

This is the web I am working on using bootstrap however I am facing some problem when using modal button with a sidebar.

Link: http://cms.host.dev4web.co/

The buttons(Statistics and Hotspot) will have a white bar when hovering over it. Anyone know how to solve this problem?

EDIT: Also is it possible to make the sidebar row scrollable?

Comment: You have the modal divs placed as children of the UL which isn't valid HTML. Try removing those modals from there and placing them after the closing UL tag and see if that helps.

Comment: Nope. The problem remains even after removing it.

Comment: Well I'd definitely move them out of the UL anyway as having them there makes the HTML invalid. TYou have a few other HTML issues which may also be affecting it. Run your page through this site to see them: http://validator.w3.org/

Answer (score 0):

I think that those two modal buttons are having that styling applied to them because they are anchor tags within a UL with the .nav class applied to it.

As such they are having some css applied to them which is meant to be applied to anchor tags within a .nav list which is overriding part of the .btn and .btn-waring & .btn-danger classes which are applied to the anchor tags.

You shouldn't really have anchor tags with the .btn classes applied with a .nav UL unless you then override the default stying for that UL in your custom css file.

This is the css from the bootstrap css file which is causing your problem.

```
.nav > li > a:hover, .nav > li > a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
}
```